# toggle the boolean value for every second continuously in C

Tags: c

How can I toggle the Boolean value continuously in a structure?

My structure

```
struct inputval
{
   int a;
   BOOLEAN b;

}
```

I need the boolean value b in the structure to toggle to true value for every second.

```
Ex:
t = 1 , b = true
t = 1.5 b = false
t = 2 , b = true
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I am confused on how to approach.Please help

Comment: What's your target platform ?  Where do you get `t` from ?  I find it __odd__ that you didn't __even__ mention that.

Comment: I am using C for this program.The t is simply an explanation for time. No real t as such.

Comment: The timing functions are not part of the C standard library. They are platform dependent features, so you must tell us at least the target plaform/os.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been established in the comments that this is about linux, here is a snippet that does what you want:

```
int b = FALSE;
while (1) { // loop forever
    b = !b;
    sleep(1);  // wait for 1 second
}
```

The problem is that this code is sequential: you can't do anything with b while the loop is running, and there is no point in having this.

The first solution is to make your code parallel. It's not easy to do that (at least not reliable), so let's find a better solution: UNIX timestamp.

The UNIX timestamp represents the number of seconds passed form 1 January 1970 (don't worry about that date, it has some historical meaning). There is a function in `time.h` called `time` that can be used to get the UNIX timestamp. Instead of having a variable that is true or false every second, you can check the parity of this value.

So, the code above is equivalent to:

```
while (1)
    b = time(NULL) % 2;
```

The difference is that in this case you don't need to keep the loop running. You just get the value of b at any point in your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot and I appreciate for taking time